# Which parts of Virāṭ Purūṣa are constituted by Varṇa Saṃkara-s & Mlechcha-s?

Tags: vedas, caste-system

The famous Purūṣa Sukta mentions [how all Varṇa-s are constituted by the Purūṣa](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/invoc/in_pura.html),

> The Brahmana (spiritual wisdom and splendour) was His mouth; the Kshatriya (administrative and military prowess) His arms became. His thighs were the Vaisya (commercial and business enterprise); of His feet the Sudra (productive and sustaining force) was born...

I tend to maintain that the mouth, arms, thighs & feet are Sattwa, Rajas, Rajas+Tamas & Tamas respectively because Vedas do talk about causes with language of their effects as commented upon by Adi Śankara in Brahman Sutra, so it's possible this verse implying the same. If it is so, then the question is answered but its' my own interpretation which might go wrong, So I am looking for the answer from scriptures, seers, ācāryā-s, etc.

So, the questions remains — Since everything sprung from the same Purūṣa, from which part did Varṇa Saṃkara-s & Mlechcha-s spring forth?

Comment: Varna Sankaras are created by the Varnas and not directly from the Purusha. Purusha just created the 4 Varnas and then the Varnas can inter-mix in all possible ways to create the Varna Sankaras.

Comment: For example if God had created humans and paddy then it's not necessary for Him to create all the dishes made out of rice. Humans can do that themselves. Similarly with the Varna Sankaras. Once the Varnas are created, they themselves can inter mix to create the Sankaras.

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary that everything and being must come directly from the Purusha.

Once the Varnas are created from the Purusha, they themselves can now inter mix to create all types of inter castes. Purusha Sukta also doesn't mention the Varna Sankaras to come directly from some portion of him.

There are only four Varnas and no fifth one. And, all those four were created by Purusha. The Varna Sankaras are the outcome of the intermixture of these created Varnas.

> Manu Smriti 10.4. Brahmana, the Kshatriya, and the Vaisya castes
> (varna) are the twice-born ones, but the fourth, the Sudra, has one
> birth only; there is no fifth (caste)

Similar arguments hold for the Mlecchas. They were originally created [from a celestial cow (called Nandini)'s tail](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mleccha).

> Mleccha (म्लेच्छ).—A tribe of people of ancient India. This tribe was
> born from the tail of the celestial cow Nandinī, kept by Vasiṣṭha for
> sacrificial purposes when there was a fight between Viśvāmitra and
> Vasiṣṭha. Mahābhārata gives the following information regarding them.
>
> The mlecchas who sprang up from the tail of the celestial cow Nandinī
> sent the army of Viśvāmitra flying in terror. (Śloka 38, Chapter 174,
> Ādi Parva). (See full article at Story of Mleccha from the Puranic
> encyclopaedia by Vettam Mani)

There are different accounts of how the Mlecchas came into existence. Like:

> 1a) Mleccha (म्लेच्छ).—Born out of the left side of Vena's body when
> the latter's body was churned;1 begin with Anu, son of Yayāti; ruled
> by Dakṣa; ruled by Turvasu; ruled by the hundred sons of Pracetas of
> Druhyu family in the east; the rule of the kings;2 not to be seen in
> Kuśadvīpa; Śakas (Parādas, Viṣṇu-purāṇa), Pallavas (Paplava,
> Viṣṇu-purāṇa) and Kāmbojas, all Mlecchas; (Ābhiras, Viṣṇu-purāṇa)
> Guruṇdas and Vṛṣalas, also belonged to this group;3 kingdoms of, found
> in the lotus coming out of the naval of the Lord;4 their kingdoms side
> by side with those of the Āryas;5 people who live in their countries
> are ineligible for Pārvana śrāddha;6 attain salvation at Benares;7 do
> not molest the women of their enemies;8 to be conquered by Kalki;9 put
> down by Pramati god.10
>
> 1b) These were the elder Madhucchandasas, who were cursed by
> Viśvāmitra to become Mlecchas;1 defeated by Bharata; these were the
> Mlecchas of the north;2 worship progenitors;3 eleven kings ruled for
> 300 years.4 Then Kolikilas followed;5 their dharma described.6

So, its not required for the Purusha to directly create them. They can come into existence much later in the phase of creation, with the basic elements needed for creation being coming directly from the Purusha.

Comment: Do you mean to say that only atomic units sprang forth from the Purusha directly?

Comment: Basic ingredients for creation all came from him as part of the sacrifice where he was offered as the Bali. Varna Sankaras need not come directly from him as the Varnas themselves are capable of creating them. Similarly for the Mlecchas. @Mr.Sigma.

Answer (score 4):

There are different origins about mlechhas origin. As per [Mahabharata;](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07089.htm) they were born from Vashishth's cow.

> And many terrible Yavanas and Paradas and Sakas and Valhikas, and **Mlecchas born of the cow (belonging to Vasishtha), of fierce eyes**

But as per Matsya Purana [Chapter 10;](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/23206/25F_Chapter_10.pdf#toolbar=0&pagemode=none&view=FitBH&page=1) they born out from King Vena's body

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502221.html)

> 17. Further, there was a mingling of these castes in due order from the higher to the lower and contrarily from the lower to the higher.
>     Thus (castes) lower than Śūdras were born from the sole of the feet.

Comment: Do you mean to say that Purusha isn't wholistic? As there is something that's not springing forth from the Purusha. It cancels lordship of the Purusha.

Comment: I have edited the answer @ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ